# Errors with using && in a WHILE loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop

There are two Sheets: `Artist` and `Artist History`. Data is copied into variables from these two sheets and compared for exact match, if it returns positive, then the `setValue` function must be executed.

I'm receiving the following error when trying to save the code:

> Missing ; before statement. (line 14, file "test")

I have no clue where the problem might be.

I've tried it with additional brackets as shown below, without additional brackets, `AND` and `&&` for the condition and still I am ending up with errors.

```
function ranking1() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Artist = ss.getSheetByName("Artist");
var Historical = ss.getSheetByName("Artist History");
var x = 8, y = 2, z = 8, n = 1;

var dList = Artist.getRange("Artist!D8:D").getValues();

var dLast = dList.filter(String).length;

var Artist1 = Artist.getRange('Artist!D'+x).getValue();
var Artist2 = Artist.getRange('Artist!A'+x).getValue();
var Artist3 = Artist.getRange('Artist!I'+z).getValue();

var History1 = Historical.getRange('Artist History!A'+y).getValue();
var History2 = Historical.getRange('Artist History!I'+y).getValue();
var History3 = Historical.getRange('Artist History!F'+y).getValue();

Logger.log(Artist1);
Logger.log(Artist2);
Logger.log(Artist3);
Logger.log(History1);
Logger.log(History2);
Logger.log(History3);  

While ((Artist1 == History1) && (Artist2 == History2) && (Artist3 == History3) && dLast>=n) { 

        Artist.getRange('B'+x).setValue(Artist3);
        n++;
        x++;
        y++;
        z--;

} 

}
```

I expect the column B8 to have the value of the variable Artist3 if the following conditions in the While loop all are positive.

Comment: How about modifying from ``While`` to ``while``?

Comment: Javascript and VBA have different syntax.

Comment: @Tanaike: wow, it actually solved it. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the syntax for while loop. Using an all lowercase `while` loop solved the issue.

```
while ((Artist1 == History1) && (Artist2 == History2) && (Artist3 == History3) && dLast>=n) { 

        Artist.getRange('B'+x).setValue(Artist3);
        n++;
        x++;
        y++;
        z--;

}
```